# Could not load file or assembly 'myApp.Web' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api

I have web application which works fine when I have configuration in Visual studio:
"Active solution configuration. Debug, platform x86."

When I publish application with release configuration(Any CPU), I get the following error on publish server:
Could not load file or assembly 'myApp.Web' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

If I change in visual studio to:
Active solution configuration, Release, platform x86.

and rebuild my application, I get the same error also on my computer.
If I change back to debug and rebuild, it works again.
I'm using Local IIS .
What could be wrong, I have tried every suggestion I have found but with no success?

Answer (score 0):

Was having same problem. This problem comes out when you are using assemblies built for x86 or x64 explicitly. Make sure that all projects, especially if you are using native code somethere in satelite assemblies are set to be built for same platform in configuration manager. 
**update**
It smells  like your server and your build machine has different bitness. If you have same bitness set for debug and release and one is working while other is not it might be because of some settings miss in assembly publish process (release does not copy something or copies something wrong)